How to have two different "extra" in the same route stack in go router for flutter?
I have the following route in my goRoute:
GoRoute(
  path: '/new-proposal-page1',
  parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  pageBuilder: (context, state) => CupertinoPage(
    child: NewProposalPage1(trip: state.extra as Trip),
  ),
),

As you can see this route requires a 'trip' object to be passed through.
From this first page, I want to navigate to a second one. I would define the route stack as follows:
GoRoute(
  path: '/new-proposal-page1',
  parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  pageBuilder: (context, state) => CupertinoPage(
    child: NewProposalPage1(trip: state.extra as Trip),
  ),
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: 'new-proposal-page2',
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      pageBuilder: (context, newProposalState) => CupertinoPage(
        child: BlocProvider.value(
          value: newProposalState.extra as NewProposalBloc,
          child: const NewProposalPage2(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ]
),

In this subroute, I need to pass the Bloc intance that I've defined in NewProposalPage1. Unfortunately, when I try to access NewProposalPage2 the system throw this error:
type 'NewProposalBloc' is not a subtype of type 'Trip' in type cast

The issue appears to be that the go Router is not able to handle two different "extra" parameters in the same route stack.
I attempted to move NewProposalPage2 out from the same route stack as NewProposalPage1, and this approach worked.
GoRoute(
  path: '/new-proposal-page1',
  parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  pageBuilder: (context, state) => CupertinoPage(
    child: NewProposalPage1(trip: state.extra as Trip),
  ),
),
GoRoute(
  path: '/new-proposal-page2',
  parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  pageBuilder: (context, newProposalState) => CupertinoPage(
    child: BlocProvider.value(
      value: newProposalState.extra as NewProposalBloc,
      child: const NewProposalPage2(),
    ),
  ),
),

but I still think that this is not the best solution as now the two pages are in two different route stacks.
Do you know how to solve the issue having the two routes in the same route stack? I searched for a solution but I was not able find something.
Thanks to all in advance!

How are you expecting to convert an object from Type to NewProposalBloc?
Not sure how it is working on the other sample, it doesn't make sense to me.
More details will be helpful.
I would go with creating the bloc on a higher level on the widget tree, so both will be able to get it from the context.read.

Hello Ramon, thank you for your response. I believe that in the second example, it is working because NewProposalPage1 and NewProposalPage2 are in two different route stacks. Therefore, state.extra is "unique" for each route stack, whereas in the first case, it is "repeated".
I would prefer to not have the bloc defined at an higher level as it could be more resource consuming. But in any case, I need to understand how can I have "more than one extra", so more than one object type, passed trough the same route
